# Unable to find Simply Cloth on blender

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have bought and downloaded Simply Cloth add on however I cannot find it on Blender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you're provided with a zip file or something, and you can hit this Install button in Preferences -> Add-Ons and choose the file.

[image]